# Finding the submodule and the endomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, modules, linear-transformations

working on some problems with modules and ran into a problem.

Let $M$ be the $\mathbb R[x]$-module $\mathbb R^2$ where $x$ acts via the linear transformation $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$
I need to find all $\mathbb R[x]$-submodule of $M$ and $End_{\mathbb R[x]} (M)$.

Could anyone share some tips on how to get started on this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The $\mathbb R[x]$-submodules of $M$ are the subspaces invariant under the action of $x$, that is, under the given linear transformation.

For the endomorphism part, note that $\phi$ is an $\mathbb R[x]$-endomorphism iff $\phi(xm)=x\phi(m)$ and this means that $\phi$ is a linear transformation that commutes with the given linear transformation.

Comment: What does "subspaces invariant" mean?

Comment: @user282639, $x \cdot U \subseteq U$.

Comment: How would I proceed with the endomorphism part?

Comment: I understand that $W$ is an $F[x]$-submodule iff $W$ is a subspace of $V$, and closed under operation $T$, but I'm not sure where to start looking for $W$'s.

Comment: @user282639, there aren't too many types of subspaces in $\mathbb R^2$...

Comment: they should be $\mathbb R^2$, ${0}$, and for any set of form {${cu : c \in \mathbb R , u \neq 0}$}?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(u,v)$ is the basis in which is written the matrix of $x$, $Vect(u)$ and $Vect(v)$ are submodule as well as the zero submodule. If $w\neq 0$ is not an eigenvector, $(w,x(w))$ is free so generated $\mathbb{R}^2$. So the only submodules are $Vect(u), Vect(v)$ and the zero submodules.

Comment: How would I proceed about the Endomorphism ring?